# Method parameter for both iostream and stringstream

Tags: c++

I'd like to input a stream parameter to a method which can be either a `<stringstream>` or `<iostream>` as in:

```
void method(? out); // or
void method(? in);
```

If `?` is `<istream>` or `<ostream>` it's straightforward. What I don't know is what to do if the parameter is either `<istream>` or `<stringstream>` or is either `<ostream>` or `<stringstream>`.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

The streams implementing both `std::istream` and `std::ostream`, e.g., `std::stringstream` and `std::fstream` derive from `std::iostream` (since they are all class templates, you'd look for `basic_...` in the standard). That is, if you really need a stream which is used for both input and output, you'd pass an `std::iostream&`.

The class `std::iostream` derives from both `std::istream` and `std::ostream`. The appropriate types are straight forward:

- for reading only use `std::istream&`
- for writing only use `std::ostream&`
- for reading and writing use `std::iostream&` (I don't think I ever used this in production code)

Note that you need to seek when switching between reading and writing in case the stream may be a file stream: switching between reading and writing without intervening seek, even if the seek is to the current position, results in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Both the string stream classes and file stream classes publically-derive from the general stream bases classes `std::basic_istream<...>` and `std::basic_ostream<...>`. This means that you can pass (for instance) `std::ostringstream` objects to functions that take `std::ostream`:

> ```
> void test(std::ostream& os);
>
> std::ostringstream buf;
> test(buf); // Good!
> ```

Unless of course, you need additional functionality specific to the derived stream classes. For example, string streams provide an `str()` method and file streams provide `open()`/`close()` member functions. In the case where you need these, you can have `test()` take string streams or file streams as parameters.

> ```
> void test(std::istringstream& iss)
> {
>      std::cout << iss.str(); // Works because the type is a stringstream
> }
> ```